# How to create a CMS that exports to a memory stick that could then update a presentation on another computer

Tags: content-management-system, usb

I have been asked to provide a solution for a client of mine.  They have asked me to build a presentation for a exhibition in a museum that can be updated.  The presentation will essentially be galleries of images/videos with associated captions.  This presentation computer will have a poor internet connection at best.

I see the best way forward for my client to update the presentation would be to have created a presentation on another computer. They need to do this remotely from exhibition and there will be no network connection between the CMS and presentation computer.

I need them to then be able to export the presentation file onto a USB stick that they could then take to the exhibition.

Once at the exhibition I would like them to be able to put the USB stick into the computer and then for it to automatically copy the information into a folder on the computer and also update a XML file.

What I'm wondering is what would be the best way to program this?  I am pretty experienced Flash and PHP programmer and would normally get round allot of these problems by running it all on networked computers running stuff from servers.  I know I could quite easily create a presentation system in flash that would load all the info from a folder but getting that folder from one computer to the other seamlessly is not something I'm familiar with.  I really don't want the administrators of the system to have to manually copy a folder from one computer to another.  It really needs to be click a button and it exports to USB and click a button and it imports from the USB.  When it comes to creating programs that export files and copy folders to and from USB sticks I'm pretty lost!!  Would this be something that needed done in C++ or something similar?  Any advice would be great!

Many thanks for taking the time to read this!

Cheers,
Craig

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several options for this but one that comes to mind is to install and run a complete stack with CMS, MySQL, webserver from a bootable USB drive/stick.

Also check http://portableapps.com/

http://bitnami.org/  may also have something for you.

Another option is to use a CMS that can export and import its content easily.

e.g. hhttp://share.ez.no/download-develop/downloads/
allows users to create content and that content ( or any section of it ) can be exported as zipped package for import into another instance of the CMS. Usually takes less than a minute each way ( unless the export is very large ).  The CMS would be installed at both locations running on the local machine. They don't need to be both running the same OS stack.